# Does an [sku] make our system any better?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I just found the tag [sku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sku). I don't see any benefit in this tag, there are 21 questions tagged with this tag.

The same goes for the tag [skus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skus) with 34 questions tagged.

Normally, a SKU is a unique identifier for an product in any kind of shop system and so on. So there's no real use for it in my opinion.

Can we burn those two tags?

Comment: Is it me or are people a bit quick lately in saying that a tag is useless?

Comment: @Stijn is not just you... useless tags appear everywhere!

Comment: Because they don't anything to either find those question nor do they add any benefit to the information given to this question in my opinion. I want to know what language whatsoever is used in this question, but now if the question is about the `sku`, the `name` or the `xdf`. I'm not going to search specifically for questions with the tag `sku`, because that's a real broad search and no technological restriction like `php`. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: So should [uuid] and [guid] be removed as well?  No.

Comment: @davidism valid argument, but on the other hand there's no [id] tag.

Comment: @KhorneHoly These (guid, sku) are data types that are absolutely valid tags. If you're seeing questions that are  poorly tagged (ie missing a language tag), then you should edit the question if you can decipher the language within the body of the question or request clarification.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Thanks for the clarification. If I see poorly tagged questions, I will retag them (or vote to close if they're not salvageable) of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say there's a specific use for it, so why does that mean it's not an appropriate tag for categorizing a question?  It means the exact opposite.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit) says there's no standard for SKUs, and that UUIDs are often used, but just because what they are isn't well defined doesn't mean their use in programming isn't either.  Just like [uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uuid) and [guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guid), [sku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sku) categorizes a type of data intended for a specific purpose.

[skus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skus) should be retagged to [sku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sku) (plurals are supposed to be blocked automatically), but the whole thing should not be removed.

Comment: Retagging `skus` to `sku` would be fine. Personally I don't see any use in it, but that's what discussion is for.